# How to detect if phone has an active data plan?

Tags: android, 3g

Is it possible to find if the phone has an active data plan i.e how does the application detect if it can use 3G to communicate with a back end server. Please point me to sample code.

Comment: You should clarify data plan.

Comment: You mean if it is currently connected to the 3G service?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, I don't think it's feasible.

**Edit** What utmost you can do is find if Internet is available or not.
         Data plan is provided by the network providers, so it's up to them.
         If they provide some sort of APIS (they won't though), then of course you can.